# Cassandra ver 1 column family

Tags: cassandra

I have following colunm family in cassandra ver 1.0.12

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY table_1(
KEY 'CompositeType(LongType, LongType)' PRIMARY KEY
) with
comparator='CompositeType(LongType, LongType)';
```

I am trying to create same in different cluster env with same version of cassandra
but when try to view table structure it shows me as below

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY table_1(
KEY blob PRIMARY KEY
) with
comparator='CompositeType(LongType, LongType)';
```

Wanted to know is this same thing ? and why is it getting represented differently?
Will it have problem when I try to copy and load sstables

Answer (score 1):

> Wanted to know is this same thing ?

Yes, it is the same thing.

> and why is it getting represented differently?

No particular reason, other than this is probably what was chosen to represent those data types in an early version of CQL.  TBH - the *current* version of CQL shows table definitions in its own format too, which is often not exactly what was typed in.  I wouldn't worry about this.

> Will it have problem when I try to copy and load sstables

No, it should be fine.

What *does* worry me, is that you're using a 10-year-old version of Cassandra.  Not only is it completely out-of-date and not supported, but you're going to have a hard time still finding documentation out there that hasn't been updated for the newer versions.  I *strongly* advise working on an upgrade to 4.x.

Comment: Thanks Aaron
For same reasons that you have mentioned here we are trying to upgrade and migrate data to ver 4.x